# Remove trailer timestamp from the captured packets

Tags: wireshark, ethernet, pcap, tcpdump, editcap

I have a packet capture captured through a special switch that appends timestamps just before FCS. These are generally referred as "trailer timestamps".

However, after doing so, the `FCS` at the end of the packet is not updated. Hence, when i load the packet capture into wireshark, all the packets are reported as having incorrect frame check sequence.

Is there a utility like `editcap` etc.. that i can use to remove, say, last `x` bytes of each packet from a `pcap`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `editcap` can remove the last `x` bytes of each packet.  From the [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) man page:

```
-C [offset:]<choplen>

    Sets the chop length to use when writing the packet data. Each packet is 
    chopped by <choplen> bytes of data. Positive values chop at the packet
    beginning while negative values chop at the packet end.
```

**Example: Remove the last 4 bytes of each packet**

```
editcap.exe -C -4 foo.pcap foo_chopped.pcap
```

Of course doing this will then result in each packet being indicated with:

```
[Packet size limited during capture: Ethertype truncated]
```

... which is of course a misleading message as the Ethertype isn't truncated, just the Ethernet frame as the FCS has been removed in this case.  Nonetheless, this is a rather harmless indication and so this solution may fit your needs.

Alternatively, you could more simply just disable Ethernet checksum validation.  Do this via `Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> Ethernet -> Validate the Ethernet checksum if possible:deslect -> OK`.

Comment: I need ethernet checksum validation. Because i am trying to debug some RX errors on a port. So, either of the solutions won't work for me. However i wrote my own application using pcapplusplus plugin to do the needful. Good to know about `editcap` feature. Thank you.

Comment: It seems we can use negative offset with editcap to treat it as index from the end. But there is some bug and editcap segfaults when i try to give negative offset..

Comment: If there's a bug in `editcap` that causes a segfault under these conditions, then I may be to blame as I authored some of this functionality.  The best way to resolve it is to open a [Wireshark Issue](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened), but before doing so, you should ensure that you're working with the latest version in case there was a known bug that was already fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Please file an issue for this on [the Wireshark issue list](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened); it might make sense to treat frames with capture-switch trailers specially.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own application using https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus

Basically you can use pcapplusplus and iterate over each RawPacket and do something like

```
rawPacket.removeData(rawPacket.getRawDataLen() - FCS_LEN - bytesToRemove, bytesToRemove);
```